# Using windows authentication to log on to Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

We have built a website that is using Windows Authentication, now the client wants to move the website to a private cloud but the client has a specific requirement. The client does not want to users to provide credentials a second time to login to Azure Active Directory, they somehow want the user' Windows login to be used to authenticate them in the Azure active directory. Can this be done? I am a novice to Azure cloud and does not know much, any help regarding this issue would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. The first thing you will need to do is to connect Active Directory with Azure Active Directory, using ADConnect. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect). Then you have 3 options to allow users to use the on premises credentials: password sync, pass through, or federation. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-user-signin) will help you to make a decision.